# Uplay DLC content downloading

Tags: far-cry-3, ubisoft-connect

I am playing from Uplay and I own a far cry 3 copy on my H drive, and got the blood dragon DLC today for free which is showing in my Uplay library and its to be downloaded. Do I need to just download it on H drive too? Or is there any other way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Far Cry 3 - Blood Dragon is a **stand-alone expansion**.

This means that you don't need Far Cry 3 in order to play this game. It doesn't matter if Far Cry 3 is installed or not, Blood dragon is a separate game.